# Making inputs to keras RNN written in Functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, masking

I'm having some problems making masking work with a keras RNN written in Functional API. The idea is to mask a tensor, zero-padded, with shape (batch_size, timesteps, 100) and feed it into a SimpleRNN. Right now I have the following:

```
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 100))

mask_layer = keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.)
mask = mask_layer(input)

rnn = keras.layers.SimpleRNN(20)
x = rnn(input, mask=mask)
```

However, this does not work, because it raises the following InvalidArgumentError:

> InvalidArgumentError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 20 and 2000. Shapes are [?,20] and [?,2000]. for 'Select' (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [?,2000], [?,20], [?,20].

By changing my Input's shape into `(None, 1)` - a sequential input where each element is a single integer, instead of n-dimensional embeddings - I've gotten this code to work. I've also gotten the same idea to work with the Sequential API, but I cannot do this, as my final model will have multiple inputs and outputs. I also do not want to force my Input's shape to be (None, 1), as I want to swap out different embedding models (Word2Vec, etc) during preprocessing, which means my Inputs will be embedding vectors from the start.

Can anyone help me with using masks with RNNs when using keras's functional API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Masking and Padding with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding), you won't need to manually set mask on the RNN layer, in the following code the RNN layer will automatically receive the mask.

```
import keras

input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 100))

masked_layer = keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.)(input_layer)

rnn_layer = keras.layers.SimpleRNN(20)(masked_layer)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.